# how to update a variable inside a runnable?

Tags: java, android, variables, runnable

the mobile variable changes based on the data traffic.
i have a button called reset.
i want the mobile variable to be set to 0 when the reset button is pressed .
if i try to change it, it says it needs to be declared final(which can't be done, since it is always going to change)
if i set mobile to global, it needs to be outside runnable and hence doesn't get updated.
please suggest a solution.

```
public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        float  mobile = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
        Button  reset =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonset);

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //what to do here
            }
        });

        float total = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        tvDataUsageWiFi.setText("" + (total - mobile) / 1024000 + " Mb");
        tvDataUsageMobile.setText("" + mobile / 1024000 + " Mb");
        tvDataUsageTotal.setText("" + total / 1024000 + " Mb");
        if (dataUsageTotalLast != total) {
            dataUsageTotalLast = total;
            updateAdapter();
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
    }
};
```

Comment: `if i set mobile to global, it needs to be outside runnable and hence doesn't get updated. please suggest a solution.` I dont get this??

Comment: it was suggested to try setting mobile variable to global so that its value can be updated outside runnable function.i was able to set it to zero but mobile didnt update itself since it was outside runnable function